# Calculation in C not following through

Tags: c

I have a soft potentiometer that I am reading position and force from through an ADC. The ADC is the ADS1015, which is why my read function is called "read_ads(...)".

I'm having trouble figuring out why the calculation: ((1-analog_val[1]/1400)*155) is ALWAYS returning 155, regardless of the value of analog_val[1]. I was trying to get a range of values from 0-155. I don't know how much more context is needed, so please ask if there is any information missing!

Thank you!!

My Program:

```
void myInterrupt (void) { 
/*
  analog_val[0] = Position (0-1750) (Baseline~=120->130)
  analog_val[1] = Force (0-1400) (tare to change baseline)
  analog_val[2] = Distance Sensor (250-900) (Baseline~=530)
  analog_val[3] = read_ads(3); // Ground
*/

  analog_val[1] = read_ads(1);
  analog_val[2] = read_ads(2);

  if (analog_val[1] > 100) {
    analog_val[0] = read_ads(0); // Position (0-1750) (Baseline~=120->130)
    z = (int)lookup[analog_val[0]];//-(int)(analog_val_1/6);
    printf("Z: %03d | ", z);
    z -= (1-analog_val[1]/1400)*155;
    printf("Z: %03d | Calc: %03d\n", z, (int)(1-analog_val[1]/1400)*155);

    z_prev = z;
  } else {
    z = z_prev;
    analog_val[0] = analog_val_prev[0];
  }



  writeBuf[0] = ((uint16_t)z >> 4) | 0b00110000;
  writeBuf[1] = (uint16_t)z << 4;

  wiringPiSPIDataRW(0, writeBuf, 2);

  analog_val_prev[0] = analog_val[0];
  //~ analog_val_prev[1] = analog_val[1];

  //~ printf("X: %04d | Y: %04d | Z: %04d\n", x, y, (int)z);
  printf("Pot Pos: %04d | Pot Force: %04d | Dist: %04d | Z: %03d\n", analog_val[0], 
  analog_val[1], analog_val[2], z);
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, when doing scaling with integers: **first** multiply, **then** divide (assuming the multiplication will not overflow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your z is int, guessing that you have more ints in your code,
`((1-analog_val[1]/1400)*155)` will be 155 for any analog_val[1] < 1400.

You might get more satisfactory results with
`((155-(analog_val[1]*155)/1400))`.

Consider using floating point math for the calculation, then output an int representation.

For best results, use a debugger to follow your values through your code, you will probably spot where they get "mistreated".

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. By casting (1 - (value < 1)) to an int, the program just truncates the (value < 1) to 0?

Comment: That is what I guess. Provide more information, e.g. a [mcve] for better analysis and answers.

Answer (score 0):

The division operator in `analog_val[1]/1400` is performing integer division, meaning any fractional part is truncated.  So if `analog_val[1]` is less than 1400, this operation will result in 0.

You need to cast this argument to `double` or use a `double` constant for the dividor. to force floating point division:

```
(1-analog_val[1]/1400.0)*155);
```